# What is the biblical basis used by Reformed theologians to argue that all those dying in infancy are saved?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, reformed-theology, infants, westminster-confession

In American Presbyterianism and Reformed theology more generally, one of the controversial issues has been the fate of children dying in infancy.  The Westminster Confession of Faith reads:

> Elect infants, dying in infancy, are regenerated, and saved by Christ ([10.3](https://www.opc.org/wcf.html#Chapter_10))

The Confession thus leaves open the possibility that *some* infants are not elect and therefore not saved, and [historically this has incited significant debate](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52703/21576).  In 1903 the PCUSA adopted a [declaratory statement](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds3.vi.ii.iii.html) affirming universal salvation of those dying in infancy, against the opposition of "old school" theologians like B. B. Warfield.  But Warfield only opposed making the position a confessional standard; personally he actually agreed with it:

> For myself, I believe with all my heart that all dying in infancy are saved, and I believe that I can prove it from Scripture. (["Does the Confession Need Revision?" II](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Revision_of_the_Confession_of_Faith/3#55))

To me this view seems problematic because Reformed theology typically holds that adults who never hear the gospel are unsaved.  So universal salvation of deceased infants would mean that some of the children of these adults go to heaven, despite neither the infants nor the adults ever having the opportunity to hear the gospel.  Why do Reformed theologians think they would be treated differently?

Other questions here deal generally with the question of infant salvation, so I'll be very specific here:

- According to Reformed theologians, what is the biblical basis for the idea that all those who die in infancy are saved?

  - Reformed theologians could include the Presbyterian opponents of Warfield, but I'm most interested in the arguments made by conservatives like Warfield.
  - I'm looking for biblical basis.  Saying "it wouldn't be fair" isn't going to cut it, unless the Bible is used to make this argument by these Reformed theologians.
  - I'm not interested in the basis for *some* dying infants being saved – I want to know the basis for *all* dying infants being saved.
  - I'm not interested in the "how" – whether dying infants have faith or not is not relevant; only that they are saved.

---

**Related questions** (and why they aren't duplicates):

- [What do Protestant churches teach about the fate of deceased infants?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50090/21576)

  - This is an overview question, not a biblical basis question.
- [How is the view of guaranteed salvation for infants justified?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32018/21576)

  - Similar, but is wider in scope, allowing for non-biblical and non-Reformed answers.  For example, the conclusion of the [accepted answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/32040/21576) is extremely questionable from a Reformed perspective.
- [What is the Biblical basis for asserting that infants can have faith in Christ under a Calvinistic framework?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14138/21576)

  - Similar, but two key differences: (1) there is a difference between infants *having faith* vs. simply *being saved* (my question is more general in this sense) and (2) my question refers to the idea of *all infants* being saved, while this question does not address that point.

Answer (score 2):

See John Piper's article: [What happens to infants who die?](http://www.desiringgod.org/articles/what-happens-to-infants-who-die)

All infants are sinners (Romans 5:12-21)

"At least" Some infants are saved: John the Baptist (Luke 1:15), David (Psalm 22:9-10).

Those not capable of perceiving good and evil are not guilty of sinful acts (John 9:41, Romans 1:20).

God is good (Psalm 119:68). Trust that he will do what is just and merciful.

Quoting Piper:

> It should also be emphasized that the salvation of all who die in
>   infancy is not inconsistent with unconditional election (the view that
>   God chooses whom to save of His own will, apart from anything in the
>   individual). As Spurgeon pointed out, it is not that God chooses
>   someone to salvation because they are going to die in infancy. Rather,
>   He has ordained that only those who have been chosen for salvation
>   will be allowed to die in infancy. God's justice in condemnation will
>   be most clearly seen by allowing those who will not be saved to
>   demonstrate their inherent sinfulness through willful, knowing
>   transgression.

Comment: Actually this article seems to have been written by a guest contributor, not Piper, though the author does quote Piper dealing with my specific question.

Comment: My bad. I was going from memory. There are other articles on the site by Piper on that topic. I shall have to dig one of them up.

Comment: Paul, those points are highly contradictory. All (infants) are sinners- contradict "some (sinners) are saved", and third - infants are not guilty of sinful acts. Also, the question seems to ask exegesis or interpretation so try to focus on direct interpretations rather than big vague deductions like that. Your point "good is good" and we should trust his justice appeals to "mystery" it is not an answer.

Comment: @michael - I merely summarize the author's argument. Reconciling justice and mercy always appears contradictory. If the Bible is true and God does not contradict himself, then all these verses are true simultaneously. Arguments appealing to an age of accountability are always squishy.

Comment: that is not an answer to appeal to mystery and make blanket summary for some passages. The conflict is with original sin to assume any single infant gets saved or dont get in hell after death. I am sure reformed theologians must have done some work explaining these things. BTW do study non-reformed (Molinist, pelagian perspective) which dont appeal to mystery http://www.reasonablefaith.org/no-other-name-a-middle-knowledge-perspective http://www.reasonablefaith.org/how-can-christ-be-the-only-way-to-god  http://www.reasonablefaith.org/Is-Molinism-as-Depressing-as-Calvinism

Comment: I'm not sure "those not capable of perceiving good and evil are not guilty of sinful acts" is widely accepted, but the problem here may be whether or not one takes "guilt" to mean "accountability". Also, it's unclear how the second (Romans 1:20) verse is supposed to apply; wrong citation? Arguing that everyone *ought* to know they are guilty? (In related news, I am reminded of [this article](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/276-original-sin-and-a-misapplied-passage) which hilariously tries to argue that children are without sin by quoting verses that *clearly* say the exact opposite!)

Answer (score 1):

In 2 Samuel 20:23, David and Bathsheba's first son together died, because of David's sin with Bathsheba and murder of her husband.  David says

v.23 " ... I will go to him one day, but he cannot return to me.”
[2 Samuel 20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%2012&version=Nkjv)

So David, a man after God's own heart, knew his infant child would be in heaven.

Comment: Also https://biblehub.com/1_kings/14-13.htm